# Is there much additional overhead between a static resource and dynamic resource in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have code like this:

```
Current.Resources["TickIconk"] = _resourcesPath + "tick.svg";

var SVG = new SvgCachedImage()
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
};
SVG.SetDynamicResource(SvgCachedImage.SourceProperty, "TickIcon");
```

TickIcon is a dynamic resource but it never changes once set.

What I would like to know is if there is any additional overhead that I should be concerned about with my making this into a dynamic resource. In particular I am most concerned about things like page draw speed.

Comment: I will also use this way to deal with a static resource and dynamic resource .

Answer (score -1):

In your case, Static resource is more efficient

Comment: HI Umair, could you try and explain your answer. Try linking to Xamarin doucmentation to help back up your answer for example.